# How to dispatch action after getting data w/subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, ngrx

After getting data with subscribe, I want to dispatch actions as below.
But both subscribe and dispatch are executed asynchronously, where no chain is forced bet. subscribe and dispatch. Also not possible to describe dispatch inside subscribe so that would cause infinite loop.

What is a better way to dispatch actions when I get a certain data from subscription?

My current code is,

```
// MyApp.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.subscribe(appState => {
        this.userId = ppState.currentUserId;
    )};

    this.store.dispatch(new LoadInitialData(this.userId);
    data$ = this.store.select('data');
}
```

My possible solution is just to implement into @Effect()...

```
// MyApp.ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadUserId());
}

//MyEffectService.ts
@Effect() loadUserId$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_USER_ID)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store.select('userId')
    .map([any, userId] => userId)
    .map(userId => new LoadInitialData(userId));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.store
  .map(appState => ppState.currentUserId)
  .do(userId => this.store.dispatch(new LoadInitialData(userId))
  .subscribe(userId => this.userId = userId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. LoadInitialData action also updates appState, then subscribe() catches the event and dispatch the action again and again. I've tried the code but I'm afraid that doesn't dork ;-(

Comment: do take(1) if u care only one one

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova How do i get it to work if i have to dispatch inside a subscribe when i am already trying to mutate the same store. Currently this solution still causes an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Use set Immediate it should dispatch event last in the loop

```
this.store.subscribe(appState => 
    setImmediate(() => {
        this.userId = ppState.currentUserId
        this.store.dispatch(new LoadInitialData(this.userId)
    })
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The "possible" solution you mentioned looks fine.

It's a good practice to keep your smart component (or container) simple, without too many business logic.

It's why, I would suggest you to rename your action to "Load" or "InitView", "Open"... to better match the real action. (here initialization of view, or view opening...). In the future, you could imagine do more things (than just load user data...) when component is initialized. Your code inside component will stay simple with only one action dispatched. Business logic remains inside your effect.

About that, have a look at this good conference from Mike Ryan : [Good Action Hygiene with NgRx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmnsEvoy-gY)

Then, it sounds perfectly good to use an effect to dispatch another action (load needed data...).

Example (without new effect/action creator syntax) :

```
// MyApp.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new Init());
}

// MyEffectService.ts
@Effect() 
init$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(Init)
  .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectors.getUserId)
  .map([any, userId] => userId)
  .map(userId => new LoadInitialData(userId));
```

PS: An other good practice is also to always use `selector` to retrieve a slice of your state. (in the example above, I used `selectors.getUserId`)